# Pandas - How do you grouby multiple columns and get the lowest value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have data frame with  75+ number of columns. I am trying to eliminate and keep the relevant data rows for a test. I just created sample data set. I know how I could tackle this in SQL group by and get all the columns. How do I do this here? I have posted one of many tries which made sense to me.

```
u_id = ['A123','A123','A123','A124','A124','A125']
year = [2016,2017,2018,2018,1997,2015]
text = ['text1','text2','text1','text1','text56','text100']


df = pd.DataFrame({'u_id': u_id,'year': year,'text':text}) 
df
```

## Data Input

```
        u_id    year    text
0   A123    2016    text1
1   A123    2017    text2
2   A123    2018    text1
3   A124    2018    text1
4   A124    1997    text56
5   A125    2015    text100
```

## Tried:

```
df[df.groupby(['u_id','year'])['year'].min()]
# error: `KeyError: '[2016 2017 2018 1997 2018 2015] not in index'`
# Key exists here, why is this an error? 'groupby/having' in SQL?
```

## Output Needed:

```
u_id    year    text      ...  col1 col2 ..... col_x
A123    2016    text1     ...
A124    1997    text56    ...
A125    2015    text100   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think,what you need is `groupby` `u_id` and keep the `min` year

```
df["year"] = pd.to_numeric(df["year"])
newdf = df.loc[df.groupby(['u_id'])['year'].idxmin()].reset_index(drop=True)
```